# Web page scraping detection

Tags: python, web-scraping, dataset, data-science

I am in the middle of a data science project and I need to scrape a few data from a web site.
Unfortunately, all the methods I have tried so far fail by getting detected by the web page:

1. requests with random agent or faking google bots
2. requests with headers of my web browser
3. selenium
4. scraper API
5. using large wait times between subsequent scrapes

Robots from the target web page is:
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /automoto/search
Disallow: /property/search
Disallow: /static_html/promo/esales/phones/
Disallow: /my/services
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:

I tried to setup puppeteer somehow but I cannot figure it out..

I find it strange that there is not a way to simulate manual code inspection and therefore information extraction without it being identified as a bot!

Do you have any suggestions? Acquiring these data is absolutely essential for delivering the project. I do not require the speed offered by web automation tools required above.

Comment: It sound like the admins of that site _don't want_ you to scrape it. That's probably in their EULA or similar. Respect their wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (puppeteer must be included)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the complications of scraping websites and getting caught, particularly Facebook (if you want to see my sneaky implementation using selenium, see [this](https://github.com/strickolas/friendless). I do not condone violating a website's terms of use, and I am not liable for your actions in violating the ToS...**BUT**

In cases where you are getting pinched for automated scraping, consider following your scraping call by an arbitrary wait call. Here's an example:

```py
import time

min_allowable_time, max_allowable_time = (1, 7)  # this is in seconds.

for x in range(0, 100):
  your_scraping_function()
  time.sleep(random.uniform(min_allowable_time, max_allowable_time))
  your_next_page_function()
```

The variate wait time is key here. You can also implement this scraper to run based on a given time of day, for example, run only from 08:00 to 22:00.

p.s. I've found it much easier to scrape mobile websites, i.e. `www.m.facebook.com`